# ffmpeg decode JPEG 2000 in multithread

Tags: c++, multithreading, ffmpeg, decode

So, I have a Video-decoder written in c++ whit help of ffmpeg library, non problem till when it comes to decode JPEG 2000 frame in multi threads, in this case the image is discontinuous, I set the context to have even number of threads and to process image slices:

```
    m->context->thread_count = m_cfgHhiThreads->value();
    m->context->thread_type = FF_THREAD_SLICE;
```

here is a sample image captured after decoding process (dimension is fine), this only happen if multithred is set [image]

Question is, why is this happening?

FFMPEG does not report any error, it actually think that the image has been correctly decoded. It is also correctly decoded the problem is in slicing.

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: does ffmpeg command line show the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that if I setup exact so many thread as the image slice number it actually work fine.